# Compare editors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, compare

I sometimes work with 2 editors in eclipse (splitting screen vertically)

I know for starters that you can compare two files by selecting them from the navigator (Ctrl + Click for example) and then hitting compare or even with a keyboard shortcut

But i am wondering if there is a way in the current release to kinda bypass the compare window which always shows up and automatically select the active file from the editor on the left and the active file from the editor on the right just like in notepad++ (where i could just have two views and hit Alt + D there and automatically the files are compared)

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in Eclipse. Of course, you're always free to write a plugin that can do what you want. The learning curve is a little steep but overall what you're describing probably wouldn't be too much work once you got the hang of plugin writing.

Here are some links to get you started:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html
- http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/resources/?sort=date&category=Plug-ins

Comment: cool, any recommendations for tutorials for plugin writing, i have a good experience in programming overall so i think a tutorial is just what i need :)